# Using PHPMailer on a godaddy hosting, im able to send a mail successfully(according to SMTPdebug = 3) but it dosent show up in the gmail inbox

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPAuth = false; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = false; 
$mail->Host = "localhost";
$mail->Port = 25; 
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3; 

$mail->Username = "my_mail"; // my_mail is created in cpanel.
$mail->Password = "my_pass";// my_pass is password while creating mail in cpanel.
$mail->SetFrom("my_mail");

$mail->Subject = "subject";
$mail->Body = $content; // content is html working perfectly on localhost.

$mail->AddAddress($email);
if(!$mail->Send()){
    echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{
echo "sent";
}
```

so I was able to send mails on localhost, and after hosting the site iv'e been stuck for almost a week.
Ive tried alot of stuff from youtube, stackoverflow, godaddy's articles, most of which are older than 3-4 years.

Seems like I'm missing some recent update here.

Comment: Often mail will get marked as spam and discarded, or re-routed to spam/junk folders, if the sender and/or the message itself doesn't appear to be reliable for some reason.  Here's a good general guide to debugging email problems in PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24644450/5947043 - although some of it's about using mail(), a lot of the points are still valid in all scenarios. You can no doubt search for broader guides which talk about configuring mailservers too, and about why mails may get rejected. You should also ask godaddy for help looking at their mailserver's logs

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything new. GoDaddy is quite bad for email. Your debug output will likely show a successful delivery *to localhost*, but you can't see what happens after that. If google bounces your message, you should receive that, but it's likely to be in your spam folder. Beyond that, as @ADyson said, you need to see GoDaddy's mail server logs.